# How to find the reference key/id in a sqlite database

Tags: python, sqlite, reference, primary-key

So I am trying to figure out the proper way to use the sqlite database, but I feel like I got it all wrong when it comes to the Key/ID part.
I'm sure the question has been asked before and answered somewhere, but I have yet to find it, so here it goes.

From what I've gathered so far I am supposed to use the Key/ID for reference to entries across tables, correct?

So if table A has an entry with ID 1 and then several columns of data, then table B uses ID 1 in table A to access that data.
I can do that and it works out just fine as long as I already know the Key/ID.

What I fail to understand is how to do this if I don't already know it.

Consider the following code:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("./DB")

conn.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Table_A  (
A_id    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE,
A_name  TEXT
)""")

conn.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Table_B  (
B_id    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE,
B_name  TEXT,
B_A_id  INTEGER
)""")

conn.execute("""INSERT INTO Table_A (A_name) VALUES ('Something')""")

conn.commit()
```

I now want to add an entry to Table_B and have it refer to the entry I just made in the B_A_id column. 
How do I do this?

I have no idea what the Key/ID is, and all I do know is that it has 'Something' in in the A_name column. Can I find it without making a query for 'Something' or checking the database directly? Cause that feels a bit backwards.

Am I doing it wrong or am I missing something here?
Maybe I am just being stupid.

Comment: No need for UNIQUE, btw. PRIMARY KEY implies that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right path, but have run into the problem that the `Connection.execute()` function is actually a shortcut for creating a cursor and executing the query using that. To retrieve the id of the new row in `Table_A` explicitly create the cursor, and access the `lastrowid` attribute, for example:

```py
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("""INSERT INTO Table_A (A_name) VALUES ('Something')""")
print(c.lastrowid) # primary key (A_id) of the new row
```

For more information about `Connection` and `Cursor` objects, refer to the [python sqlite3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sqlite3.html).

Comment: Ah, will have to remember that one. It only works right after you create the line though right? But I guess that is when you actually want to use it anyways. I'll try to use this in my next project, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to know the `A_id` from `Table_A`.
All you need is the value of the column `A_name`, say it is `'Something'`, which you want to reference in `Table_B` and you can do it like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table_B (B_name, B_A_id)
SELECT 'SomethingInTableB', A_Id 
FROM Table_A 
WHERE A_name = 'Something'
```

or:

```
INSERT INTO Table_B (B_name, B_A_id) VALUES 
('SomethingInTableB', (SELECT A_Id FROM Table_A WHERE A_name = 'Something'))
```

Comment: Thought it would be something like that, but that is the part that has me confused. I feel I could just as well just use "something" to find it. I guess with the ID it would lock it into that specific row in case "somthing" got changed, but not sure when I would need that.